# Como criar divs dentro do php

Tags: php, html

Preciso criar divs que serão populadas por objetos de uma classe, tenho em mente que será preciso utilizar um foreach criando uma div para cada objeto, porém não sei como devo chamar e posicionar essas divs no html, se é via ajax ou de outro modo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim, por exemplo:

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
      <li><?php echo $item; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Referência:

- [Sintaxe alternativa para estruturas de controle no PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php);
- [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: vou tentar implementar vlw